# Add Button to UISlider Thumb

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uislider

I am developing an application in which i have to play an audio file. Using UISlider am able to rewind and forward the track. Now the issue i'm facing is that i have to put the play button on slider thumb(as shown in below image).

[image]

I know that we can set the thumb image to slider, but couldn't find solution for adding the button the slider thumb. Also i doubt whether it is possible to add the button on slider thumb. Is it possible using custom slider? or is there any alternate solution to it.
Please suggest..! Thanks

Comment: You are trying to mix two interactions which is bad, what happens when the user moves the slider? does it change the play/pause state?

Comment: yeah you are right this would mix up the two functionalities. But is it possible if it has to be implement as per the requirement.